# ValueError: The MD5 checksum of local file yolov3.weights differs from c84e5b99d0e52cd466ae710cadf6d84c

Tags: yolo, tensorrt

I am struck in a problem, I was trying to perform prediction of my customized YOLO model (yolov3.weight) with tensorrt. I was struck in the below step (converting yolo to onnx). I am having my own yolov3.weights.

For converting the yolo to onxx, I was using the python file (yolov3_to_onnx.py) in location 
/usr/src/tensorrt/samples/python/. In this file I am loading my customized trained yolov3.weight.

While running the file

```
python2 yolov3_to_onnx.py
```

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yolov3_to_onnx.py", line 812, in <module>
main()
File "yolov3_to_onnx.py", line 793, in main
'c84e5b99d0e52cd466ae710cadf6d84c')
File "yolov3_to_onnx.py", line 750, in download_file
(local_path, checksum_reference))
ValueError: The MD5 checksum of local file yolov3.weights differs from c84e5b99d0e52cd466ae710cadf6d84c, please manually remove the file and try again
```

I am struck here and don't know how to find the MD5 checksum of local file yolov3.weights. I believe that yolov3_to_onnx.py is using MD5 checksum of the pretrained yolov3.weight.

I have searched on the internet about MD5 checksum but is unable to know how to find the such for my customized yolov3.weight. I also came to know that this is very important for checking the authenticity.

Please see the file [yolov3_to_onnx.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19wZa6UddHXkQYlZnULRYBRsKmT7k9m2R/view?usp=sharing) where I am struck. For more help, I am adding the code snippet from this file which is the real case of this problem.

```
weights_file_path = download_file(
        'yolov3.weights',
        'https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights',
        'c84e5b99d0e52cd466ae710cadf6d84c')
```

I hope, if c84e5b99d0e52cd466ae710cadf6d84c checksum is replaced by md5 checksum of my weight, then problem will be resolved but i don't know how to find the checksum for my customized yolov3 weights.